# Proper implementation of Firebase JavaScript SDK and AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've been using AngularFire because of its simple code and it saves you from tons of code if you're doing vanilla JavaScript and Firebase.

So I have a controller:

```
function sampleCtrl($scope, $firebaseArray) {
   var counter = 0;
   var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('reports')
   $scope.reports = $firebaseArray(ref);
   $scope.reports.$loaded(function () {
      counter = $scope.reports.length;
   })
}
```

And let's say I currently have 3 items in my reports `ref` so the value of the variable `counter` will be `3`.

Now my problem is, I wanted to increment it whenever there's a new data. So this is what I did since I can't do it already with AngularFire:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function (data) {
    counter++;
});
```

The counter value is expected to become `4` for example if there's new data, but it becomes 6 because it still counts everything. So whenever there's new data, the `counter` variable doubles.

Is there a trick for this? Or maybe a better way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you just using $scope.reports.length? Which already contains the value you've requested and properly updates with Angular's compiler? Not really clear when you expect this to increment, other than once per record received. Also, avoid $loaded; it's generally the wrong answer.

Comment: @Kato Thank you. That actually works, though my problem now is I want to play a sound when there's new child_added

Comment: You can also use `$firebaseArray.$watch` to watch for changes and respond with sound, or whatever you want.

Comment: @idan will try that. For now I only need child_added so that I can play a sound